# Fixed element visible at certain height

Tags: css, css-position

Is there a way to force a fixed element to show up at certain height without using javascript? I have a fixed element that should act as a menu but should only be visible after the first 900px of the site are scrolled down and from that point onward right now it's a simple fixed menu:

```
#actual-menu{
    margin-top:50px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:20px;
}
```

however if I leave "top:20px" then I see it before the 900px are scrolled and if I make it 920px then I never see it. Is there a way to get it to "wait" until the user is there and then move? (with only css preferably)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with CSS, but jQuery made it very easy:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
        $('#divmenu').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('#divmenu').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: trying this this it only fadesout when I scroll all the way to top but doesn't register anything below that =/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you used absolute?

```
    #actual-menu{
    margin-top:50px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:920px;
}
```

Of course this way it will scroll up instead of pop out, and also `top:920px` should change accordingly to the parent element... Otherwise I recommend using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

@Luis, Try this

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="divmenu"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main{
    width:100%;
    height:1500px;
    background:#CCC;
}
#divmenu{
    margin-top:50px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    background:#000;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
        $('#divmenu').fadeIn('slow',function(){$(this).css({'width':'100px', 'height':'100px'});});
    } else {
        $('#divmenu').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```